# Why is hypothesis of Tate's theorem is satisfied by Galois group of unramified extension of a local field?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, homology-cohomology, group-cohomology, class-field-theory

I am reading Milne's notes on Class Field Theory. https://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/CFT.pdf

On page 99, in the section 'The Local Artin Maps' he says,

> Let $L$ be a finite unramified extension of a local field $K$ with Galois group $G$. Then the pair $(G, L^{\times})$ satisfies the hypothesis for Tate's theorem.

Tate's theorem requires $G$ to be finite which it is and also for each $H \leq G $ we want  $H^1(H, L^{\times})=0 $ and $H^2(H, L^{\times})$ is cyclic and of order   $|H|$.
Tate's theorem then gives us that $$H^r_T(G, \mathbb Z) \cong H^{r+2}_T(G,L^{\times}) $$

I am trying to understand why this holds i.e. why Tate's theorem's hypothesis is being satisfied by $(G, L^{\times})$.

We know $H^1(G,L^{\times})=0 $ from Hilbert's theorem 90. But how to prove this for subgroups $H$ of $G$? It is possible to deduce if we had a way to extend homomorphism form $H$ to $G$.

I have not got $H^2$ either.

Feel free to give any reference. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Every subgroup of $G$ is of the form $\operatorname{Gal}(L/E)$ for some intermediate extension $L/E/K$.

Comment: For $H^2$ it's a Brauer group.

Comment: If $H\le G$ we are looking at cohomology for the extension $L/L^H$ which is also unramified.

Comment: For the Brauer-group question, this statement is [Serre - Local fields](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4757-5673-9), Chapter XIII, Section 3.

Comment: @LSpice thank you! Why didn't I think of that! Hilbert 90 gives result for $H^1$ and the inv map for $H^2 $.